# Adding space after two columns in GrdiView

Tags: android, gridview

I am Using a GridView in my application which has four columns. I want to add equal spaces between first and last two columns which i have done but i want to add more space between first and last two columns. I mean after second column i need more space so as two separate the pair of columns.

Comment: Give margin your Gridview custom row layout. You want to give the space between second and third column then you can give marginRight to second column or marginLeft to third column.

Comment: Programmatically add margin or padding in gridview adapter as per position.

Answer (score 0):

in your grid view adapter

```
view.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);
```

where `view` is the one you want to inflate, in this case padding will be in px
,to get it in dp use

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dpAsPixels = (int) (sizeInDp*scale + 0.5f);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels